# SQL Server - Columnstore index on Decimal(22,6) datatype

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, precision, columnstore

We have a SQL Server 2012 database with a number (over 500) of numeric columns in different tables. Our standard datatype is `Decimal(22,6)`.

However when I tried I found out we can't create a columnstore index on the `decimal` datatype with a precision of over 18.

Has this issue been resolved in SQL Server 2014/2016? Is there a workaround for this limitation?

Comment: You stated your *standard datatype is decimal(22,6)*. This sounds like lazy DDL creations. Why not set the column size appropriately? Everything shouldn't be 22,6 unless you expect a value to reach that level. Otherwise, you are just consuming necessary spaces, making your indexes and tables larger, and slowing things down.

Comment: @scsimon I understand the point regarding saving space and performance however , Decimal(22,6) is standard for certain type of data users are interested in and not all data. This enables standardization.